# Dynamic SQL with variable amount of parameters

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamic-sql, execute-immediate

I know the following works (this would be part of the code inside a stored procedure):

```
sql_string := 'INSERT INTO my_table (data_id, data_col) SELECT SYS_GUID(),''{"json_id1":'' || (:value_1 - val_from_view_1 + :i - 1) || ''}'' FROM my_view WHERE col_1 <= :value_2';

FOR i IN 1..N LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_string
    USING IN OUT input_value_1, i, input_value_2;
END LOOP;
```

My question is, since that `sql_string` comes as an input parameter to my stored procedure, how do I deal with a variable number of parameters for the `USING` clause? That is, how do I cover the above case, a case where the `sql_string` is such that I have something like this:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_string
USING IN OUT input_value_1, i, input_value_2, ..., input_value_N;
```

and everything in between?

PS: I'm not married to `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`, so if there's a better way to do this, feel free to suggest it.

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I want to be able to execute a SQL statement that comes as an input parameter to a stored procedure. That SQL statement in turn can ha a variable number of parameters, some which depend on values calculated outside or inside the loop, or even the index of the loop the <code>EXECUTE IMMEDIATE</code> is contained in.

Comment: From your example I don't see any reason to use dynamic SQL at all. Did you try static command? E.g. `INSERT INTO my_table (data_id, data_col) SELECT SYS_GUID(), '{"json_id1":' || (input_value_1 - val_from_view_1 + i - 1) || '}' FROM my_view WHERE col_1 <= input_value_2;`

Comment: The SQL statement will be dynamically generated and can vary widely in size (and of course complexity). The above is just a simple example, but the JSON this generates per record can be any size depending on the type of object it's associated with.